# Problem when changing the font size in nedit

Tags: rhel, fonts, editors

Whenever I open Nedit, the following error appears ----

```
Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-o-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Cannot convert string "-*-courier-bold-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct

Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-o-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type 
FontStruct
```

Im unable to edit the font style in preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nedit, like other old Motif (and Xaw) applications, depends on server-side fonts

Most times, `nedit` complains like that because some font, like `xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi`, is either missing or, for some reason, not in your `Xorg` font path.
Usually, installing that font (e.g. `xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi`) solves the problem.
If not, add it to your font path, either via `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-fonts.conf`:
e.g.

```
Section "Files"
    FontPath    "/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi"
    FontPath    "/usr/share/X11/fonts/cantarell"
    FontPath    "/usr/share/X11/fonts/encodings"
    FontPath    "/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc"
    FontPath    "/usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF"
EndSection
```

or via `~/.xinitrc`:

```
xset fp+ /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi
```

Alternatively, you could test in terminal:

```
xset fp+ /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi
nedit
```

Note: I'm not using RHEL so you might have to adjust paths accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of searching, I did this, and it works (on Ubuntu Precise, other OS versions may have different package install commands). All the nedit FontStruct errors are gone. :)

```
xlsfonts # Will show no fonts (or the wrong ones)
xset q # Shows no font paths
apt-cache search xfonts # Find them
sudo apt-get install xfonts-traditional # install them
# Answer no if it wants to reconfigure Xterm
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
# Not sure how many you need, I used these 3 packages.
# Pay attention to paths where apt-get puts them.
# Mine ended up here, e.g.
ls  /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/
# Tell X which paths to find them:
xset fp+ /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ # Configure X
xset fp+ /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/
xset fp rehash # Make X reload
```

All better now. Now if only someone would update nedit to a modern font system...